# Combine and plot multiple stars proxy objects (being read by read_ncdf)

Tags: gdal, r, netcdf, sf, stars

Here is a great ressource on how to combine data in the `stars` package: https://tmieno2.github.io/R-as-GIS-for-Economists/merging-stars-objects-using-c-and-st-mosaic.html

And here is a great ressource on how to work with `stars-proxy`-objects: https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/articles/stars2.html

Yet I wonder on how to combine these two. I have mulitple NetCDF files where has a time-dimension. I want to create one single stars proxy object with all timestamps from all the NetCDF files.

The data and the script can be found here: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1AEKu4TKpzJg95oXv8dxep24xpXaesr0F

The code looks as this:

```
library(purrr)
library(stars)


# files -------------------------------------------------------------------
files = dir(".", pattern = ".*\\.nc$", full.names = T)
files = files[1:2]

# proxy data --------------------------------------------------------------
data = map(files[1:2], ~read_ncdf(.x, var="SDU", proxy = F))
data_proxy = map(files[1:2], ~read_ncdf(.x, var="SDU", proxy = T))

# combine -----------------------------------------------------------------
comb = do.call("c", data)
comb_proxy = do.call("c", data_proxy)

## works!!
plot(comb)

## does not work!
plot(comb_proxy)
```

The combined `stars-proxy`-object looks like this:

```
netcdf source stars proxy object from:
[1] "[...]/SDUms2023010100000042310001I1MA.nc" "[...]/SDUms2023020100000042310001I1MA.nc"

Available nc variables:
attr

dimension(s):
     from   to  refsys point                         values x/y
lon     1 2600  WGS 84 FALSE      [2600] -64.975,...,64.975 [x]
lat     1 2600  WGS 84 FALSE      [2600] -64.975,...,64.975 [y]
time    1    2 POSIXct    NA 2023-01-01 UTC, 2023-02-01 UTC
```

However, when plotting I get this error (which I do not get when not reading in as proxy):

```
Error in if (nchar(x) < 1) stop("NetCDF source cannot be empty string") : 
  the condition has length > 1
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Or is there a "better" way on how to potentially create a really big NetCDF (from multiple) and maybe write it to disk?